# How do I update dynamic array inside useEffect in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have an array declared as

```
 var subjects : string[] = [];
```

Then set the array with the values as

```
subjects.push("C")
subjects.push("C++")
```

Then I want to update this array from useEffect. I tried below code

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    subjects.push("Java")
  },[])
```

when displaying subjects array, it is not updating with "Java".
Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: could you provide the whole React Component ?

Comment: It will not work because the UI will update only when the states changes, put your array inside useState() methods and then use setState after array is updated

Comment: You're using a plain Array and mutating this in an effect. This never works in React as it doesn't know the Array has changed. You should use `useState` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not triggering any re-rendering of your component. Re-renders run when `props` or states changes. You are trying to update an immutable piece of data in React world instead and the algorithm doesn't know that it changed, the UI doesn't reflect the updated subjects array as consequence.

So you could declare your subjects array in this way using the `useState` hook:

```
const [subjects, setSubjects] = useState<string[]>(["C++", "C"])
```

Then you can update it in this way:

```
setSubjects((prev) => [...prev, 'Java']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use hook useState for creating your array.

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState<string[]>([])
```

And if you want change array, you should set new value as setValue([...value, "Java"]);

Answer (score 0):

Declare a state hook and store `subjects` values in it.

```
const [subjects, setSubjects] = useState<string[]>(["C", "C++"]);
```

Then in `useEffect` change the `subjects` value:

```
useEffect(()=>{
   const currentSubjects = [...subjects];
   currentSubjects.push("Java");
   setSubjects(currentSubjects);
},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

because you aren't using state variable(useState) and your subjects array has Java inside but that can't be visible until your component gets re-rendered so in my opinion you should use `const [subjects, setSubjects] : string[] = useState<string[]>([])`
and in useEffect:-

```
useEffect(()=>{
setSubjects([...subjects, 'Java']);},[])
```

Comment: `const [subjects, setSubjects] : string[]` is not a valid type and don't need it.